# Modifying remote repo without local checkout

Tags: git

`git ls-remote` works without a local git checkout and displays references with the associated commit IDs.

`git push` modifies remote refs but requires a local checkout.

How can I modify remote refs without having a local checkout? I know `ssh` and `git update-ref` is a possibility but I am wondering whether there's a `git` command for this.

Comment: do you mean: you want to update a branch to point to an already existing commit ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: I still don't know a standard command to do this (sending a reference to a commit you actually don't have locally to update a branch). You could check the pack protocol to see if updating a branch that way is doable: https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-protocol/2.2.3 , but that's definitely low level. You would also have to check whether this triggers the expected "push" hooks on the server side, or if this would circumvent them.

Comment: Further looking into `git ls-remote` with `GIT_SSH_COMMANDS='ssh -v'` also lead me to think of packs because it runs `git-upload-pack`, thanks for the pointer, that definitely looks useful!

Comment: @LeGEC is there a way to capture the packfile `git push` sends for further investigation? Maybe a blobless push doesn't need much...

Comment: there are several env vars which can turn on debugging information: see [the book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_debugging) and [`git help git`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITTRACEcode). You prabably want to try `GIT_TRACE_PACKET=1`

Answer (score 1):

> `git push` modifies remote refs but requires a local checkout.

That's not quite true, you can push from a bare repository just as easily as a work-tree'd one.

You can fetch just the minimal sketch of history, just enough to see the structure, just bare commit metadata, with

```
git clone --bare --filter=tree:0 github:example/repo
cd repo.git
```

then from there you can set branch tips to whatever you want

```
git push origin +$anycommit:refs/heads/somebranch
```

Add `--no-mailmap` to any `git log`s you do (like `git log --no-mailmap --graph --oneline --all` to see the commit structure) to get a commit id for the `$anycommit` above when using a truncated fetch like this, otherwise `git log` looks for a `.mailmap` file (and hence fetches the tree and the file if it exists) at each referenced tip.

Comment: This still needs over six seconds to run, alas. If `--depth=1` worked that would be great but it does not. I guess that's a different question.

Comment: If you want to build a service that can allow callers to update refs or do whatever you want,, it's not hard to do that with a pre-receive hook watching for special refs you choose to respond to, but then the question becomes, how does the caller see what they're working on without having at least a sketch of the repo already? You're going to have to provide some concrete details about what you're doing, your exact intended work flow, if you want help constructing it.

Comment: There's a third party hosting system I tie into it, it builds on push, works well for developers, want to make the life of QA faster so they don't need checkouts around. There really isn't more than a git push --force to it which deploys a branch on a named test environment (named means it's in DNS, devs can work from unnamed ones)

Comment: @chx: perhaps you can find a way to trigger a build job from a commit hash trhough some other mean ? (for example: an http call via `curl ...` to a specific api route ....)

Comment: @LeGEC as you can see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77210784/308851 I implemented this in go, it's not even hard.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented this in `go`. It does not use any git libraries.

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha1"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/agent"
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    checkArgs("<servername>", "<repository path>", "<hash>", "<name>")
    serverName := os.Args[1]
    repositoryPath := os.Args[2]
    hash := os.Args[3]
    name := os.Args[4]

    sshOutput, sshInput := sshOpen(serverName, repositoryPath)

    // git receive-pack prints all the hashes and names on connection, find the
    // current hash for this name.
    oldHash := getOldHash(sshOutput, name)

    // This is the update command.
    updateCommand := oldHash + " " + hash + " " + name + "\x00"
    // Convert it into a PKT-LINE by prefixing it with the length.
    // The prefix needs to be four hexadecimal digits and the length includes
    // this prefix.
    pktLine := fmt.Sprintf("%04x", len(updateCommand)+4) + updateCommand
    io.WriteString(sshInput, pktLine)
    // Commands are terminated by a flush PKT which is just 0000.
    io.WriteString(sshInput, "0000")
    // After the commands, a packfile must be sent. This is an empty one.
    // "PACK" header, packfile version (2) and the number of objects (0).
    packfile := append([]byte("PACK"), 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    // Send the contents of the packfile.
    sshInput.Write(packfile)
    // Calculate and send the hash of the packfile.
    h := sha1.New()
    h.Write(packfile)
    sshInput.Write(h.Sum(nil))
}

func sshOpen(serverName string, repositoryPath string) (io.Reader, io.Writer) {
    sshAgent, err := net.Dial("unix", os.Getenv("SSH_AUTH_SOCK"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to SSH agent: %v\n", err)
    }

    config := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: "git",
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{
            ssh.PublicKeysCallback(agent.NewClient(sshAgent).Signers),
        },
        HostKeyCallback: ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey(),
    }

    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", serverName, config)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to connect to SSH server: %v\n", err)
    }

    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create SSH session: %v\n", err)
    }

    sshOutput, err := session.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create sshOutput pipe: %v\n", err)
    }
    sshInput, err := session.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create sshInput pipe: %v\n", err)
    }
    err = session.Start("git-receive-pack '" + repositoryPath + "'")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to start remote command: %v\n", err)
    }
    return sshOutput, sshInput
}

func getOldHash(sshOutput io.Reader, name string) string {
    prefix := make([]byte, 4)
    first := true
    oldHash := "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

    for {
        // Read the 4-character length prefix in hexadecimal format.
        n, err := sshOutput.Read(prefix)
        if n != 4 || err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Invalid response: %v\nRead %d bytes, error: %v", prefix, n, err)
        }
        // Convert it to integer (64 is the bitsize)
        length, err := strconv.ParseInt(string(prefix), 16, 64)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Invalid response: %v\n", prefix)
        }
        // This is the end.
        if length == 0 {
            break
        }
        // We already read four bytes of this PKT-LINE
        length -= 4
        buf := make([]byte, length)
        n, err = sshOutput.Read(buf)
        if int64(n) != length || err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Invalid response: %v", buf)
        }
        // The first line is hash space name zero byte capabilities.
        // Subsequent lines are hash space name linebreak.
        // See example client/server communication at https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-protocol/#_report_status
        separator := "\x0A"
        if first {
            separator = "\x00"
        }
        if strings.HasPrefix(string(buf[41:]), name+separator) {
            oldHash = string(buf[:40])
        }
        first = false
    }
    return oldHash
}

func checkArgs(arg ...string) {
    if len(os.Args) < len(arg)+1 {
        log.Fatalf("Usage: %s %s", os.Args[0], strings.Join(arg, " "))
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I still don't know a standard command to do this: sending a reference to a commit you actually don't have locally to update a branch.

You could check the pack protocol to see if updating a branch that way is doable:
https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-protocol/2.2.3

but that's definitely low level.

You would also have to confirm if other actions, such as server side hooks, get triggered correctly if you interact with the server in that way.

Comment: I neither want to commit nor I want to push. I want to modify remote refs.